# wpf usercontrol, border cornerradius not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a usercontrol that is surrounded with a bordercontrol. What I want is that I can set the borderbrush through a property when I am placing the control. I can set the color of the border but the problem is that the cornerradius is not working. The only way it works is if I set the borderbrush in the usercontrol itself.
Evertything else is working just fine. I can set the text properties for the labels and the image property for the Image but I cannot find out why the cornerradius is not working.

```
    <UserControl x:Class="CoinManager.Controls.AltCoinButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CoinManager.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="80" Width="80">
<Border Name="crtBorder" 
        BorderThickness="1" 
        Padding="5"
        CornerRadius="5"    
        BorderBrush="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
    <Grid>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:AltCoinButton, AncestorLevel=1}}" 
               Height="25" Width="25"
               />
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=ContentCoinType, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:AltCoinButton, AncestorLevel=1}}"
                Foreground="#FAFAFA"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0"
               FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=ContentCoinValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:AltCoinButton, AncestorLevel=1}}"
               Foreground="#FAFAFA"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-10,0,0"
               FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
</Border>
```

Here is the code in my custom project.

```
    <Controls:AltCoinButton x:Name="btcButton"
        Height="80"
        Width="80" ImageSource="{StaticResource BtcLogo}"
        BorderBrush="#FF9900" 
        ContentCoinType="Bitcoin" 
        ContentCoinValue="€ 1544,23" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="186,50.254,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height"/>
```

Can anyone of you help me out?

Comment: Please delete this question.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. It turned out I had implemented the wrong relative for the borderbrush source. In stead of:

```
    BorderBrush="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
```

It should have been:

```
    BorderBrush="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:AltCoinButton, AncestorLevel=1}}">
```